# Hirzebruch's ICM talk

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, differential-topology, complex-manifolds

Is there an English translation of Hirzebruch's 1958 ICM lecture note:

KOMPLEXE MANNIGFALTIGKEITEN

Thank you very much!

Comment: At least the title means "complex manifolds"... but you probably know it since you tagged it :-)

Comment: Google translate will get you quite far. For example, the opening paragraph "Es soll einerseits über Resultate von Münor über fast-komplexe Mannigfaltigkeiten berichtet werden und andererseits über die neue Formulierung des Satzes von Riemann-Roch für algebraische Mannigfaltigkeiten beliebiger Dimension durch Grothendieck." is rendered by Google as "It is on the one hand on results of Münor almost-complex Multiplicities are reported , and the other, on the new Formulation of the theorem of Riemann-Roch for algebraic manifolds of arbitrary dimension by Grothendieck." Clear enough, I think.

Comment: I apologize, but of course it says "Resultate von Milnor" and not Münor. Milnor, J. W. On the cobordisme ring Q.*, and a complex analogue.